# How to get started on making a custom payment system using PHP?

Tags: php, validation, shopping-cart, payment

Let's say, for the sake of discussion, my client does not want to use the Paypal api for transactions. I have already made a shopping cart. The user submits the items on the shopping cart and their credit card number.

Assuming I'm not using any api, how would I then charge the user's credit card for the items on the shopping cart? I understand that it is complex, just wondering what the general process is like and how to get started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to need to trigger a bank transaction, so obviously you're going to need to use an API at some level. I think the way to go would be to first learn in some detail how at least one of the popular commercial (by definition?) payment card processing services works, e.g.:

- https://paymentvision.com/Payment-Gateway/Payment-Gateway-API.aspx
- http://aws.amazon.com/fps/
- https://www.firstdata.com/en_us/customer-center/merchants/support/first-data-global-gateway-api-software-landing.html
- http://www.authorize.net/

The next step would be to design the "payment processing" subsystem of your PHP application/library around the "backend workflow" (perhaps using a 3rd party PHP library, if one is available), and do some testing.

Then I would plan for a security audit of your code & systems before you actually use it to handle payment card information on behalf of a customer/3rd party.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Have you looked at [the Amazon FPS FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/fps/faqs/)?

Comment: I mean, when Amazon handles credit card payments from their customers, they would also use an api, according to your explanation? So the company itself also uses Amazon FPS? I'll read the FAQ when I have the time.

Comment: Well, companies as big as Amazon can afford to run their own [ACH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_Clearing_House) and [EPN](http://www.epaynetwork.com/home.php) operations, so I wouldn't assume that there's a single API used internally by Amazon for processing payments. But individuals and [SMBs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_and_medium_enterprises) really have no choice but to pay for a service, and each service has an associated API. That's what I meant by "you're going to need to use an API at some level".

Answer (score 4):

You can also capture all the card information and use an external payment processor.  The problem is that you will be hit with major fees since it will be considered a keyed in and not swiped transaction.

If you don't want/like paypal, don want to use a payment processor like authorize.net, you could look at other options like stripe.com.

Comment: Also note, that if you are going to "roll your own" in some way you need to be careful with what and how you do it.  https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/

Comment: never heard of stripe.  Great suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Find an payment gateway, such as authorize.net.  With payment gateways such as this, your client will need to sign up for a merchant account with a credit card processing agency.  You payment gateway can help you with this.

Then, you'll usually get a token or api key that you will use to connect to the payment gateways services.  From php, you'll use cURL or fsockopen to connect to them.  Securely send your api key, get a response, then send some other required message, get another response, and then send in credit card information and credit card holder information.

There are lots of PHP Libraries to choose from out there for different payment gateways.  I'm not suggesting authorize.net, it was just an example.  But when you find one you are happy with, and happy with the fees that are associated with processing credit cards, you can either use a prewritten library, or they payment gateway will provide you with and API that will tell you how to integrate with their system.

Answer (score 0):

[Payum](https://payum.forma-pro.com/) efficiency proved by [1k+ stars on a GitHub](https://github.com/Payum/Payum), great comments and [a million of downloads](https://packagist.org/packages/payum/). Supports 50+ different payment gateways so you surely find what you need.